# Error in execution of multi2sim simulator

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, gcc

```
cust@cust:~$ cd ~/Desktop/multi2sim-5.0
cust@cust:~/Desktop/multi2sim-5.0$ g++ matx.cpp -o matx
cust@cust:~/Desktop/multi2sim-5.0$ ./matx
Enter the order of matrix (must be n*n) 
1
 * 1

Multiplication possible 

Enter the elements of matrix 1 
23

Elements of matrix 1 are 
23 
Enter the elements of matrix 2 
12

Elements of matrix 2 are 
12 
Multiplication 

276 cust@cust:~/Desktop/multi2sim-5.0$ m2s --x86-debug-syscall stdout matx

; Multi2Sim 5.0 - A Simulation Framework for CPU-GPU Heterogeneous Computing
; Please use command 'm2s --help' for a list of command-line options.
; Simulation alpha-numeric ID: SHxSw


[ELF Reader] [/home/cust/Desktop/multi2sim-5.0/matx] Error: 64-bit ELF files not
supported



The ELF file being loaded is a 64-bit file, currently not supported by
Multi2Sim. If you are compiling your own source code on a 64-bit machine, please
use the '-m32' flag in the gcc command-line. If you get compilation errors
related with missing '.h' files, check that the 32-bit gcc package associated
with your Linux distribution is installed.
```

Comment: How to solve the above problem?

Comment: What problem? Please [edit] your question (don't use the comments) and ask an actual question. Also tell us what you are trying to do and what is happening. What are you compiling? Where did you get it?

Comment: Seems very clear :  `64-bit ELF files not supported` .... Which OS have you got ? Like Ubuntu 14.04 - amd64 / x86_64 ...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running a 64-bit Linux, but that application you use doesn't support 64-bit binaries for simulation.
So just add

```
-m32
```

to your g++ line.

```
g++ -m32 matx.cpp -o matx
```

As suggested:

> The ELF file being loaded is a 64-bit file, currently not supported by
>   Multi2Sim. If you are compiling your own source code on a 64-bit
>   machine, please use the '-m32' flag in the gcc command-line. If you
>   get compilation errors related with missing '.h' files, check that the
>   32-bit gcc package associated with your Linux distribution is
>   installed.

Comment: I tried that commond , but still show that error